# Summation of $\sum_{r=1}^n \sin(2r-1)\theta$

Tags: complex-numbers, summation-method

In a CIE A Level Further Mathematics question paper, the following question appeared:

> By considering $$\sum_{r=1}^n z^{2r-1}$$ where $z=\cos\theta +i\sin\theta$, show that if $\sin ≠ 0$,
>
> $$\sum_{r=1}^n \sin(2r-1)\theta =\frac{\sin^2n\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

My attempt at solving this:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n z^{2r-1}=z+z^3+z^5+...z^{2n-1}=\frac{z((z^2)^n-1)}{z^2-1}$$
Then, expanding the brackets and dividing the numerator and denominator by $z$,
$$\frac{z^{2n}-1}{z-z^{-1}}$$
Applying de Moivre's theorem, we get
$$\frac{\cos(2n\theta)+i\sin(2n\theta)-1}{2i\sin\theta}$$
Since we only need the imaginary part,
$$\operatorname{Im}\left(\sum_{r=1}^n z^{2r-1}\right)=\frac{\cos(2n\theta)-1}{2\sin\theta}$$
Lastly, applying the double angle formula,
$$\frac{-\sin^{2}(n\theta)}{\sin\theta}$$
Maybe I'm being completely oblivious to one single elementary error, but what mistake have I made to get a negative sign?

Comment: Consider $\sum \sin(2r-1)\theta = \sum \Im e^{(2r-1)\theta i} = \Im \sum e^{(2r-1)\theta i}$.

Comment: Is it because $1/i=-i$?  (The line starting with "Since we only need the imaginary part...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation should be

$$
\eqalign{
\Im\left(\frac{\cos\left(2n\theta\right)+i\sin\left(2n\theta\right)-1}{2i\sin\left(\theta\right)}\right) &= \Im\left(\frac{\cos\left(2n\theta\right)}{2i\sin\left(\theta\right)}+\frac{\sin\left(2n\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}-\frac{1}{2i\sin\left(\theta\right)}\right) \cr
&= \Im\left(\frac{\sin\left(2n\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}+\frac{i}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}-\frac{i\cos\left(2n\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}\right) \cr
&= \frac{1}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)}-\frac{\cos\left(2n\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)} \cr
&= \frac{1-\cos\left(2n\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\theta\right)} \cr
&= \frac{\sin^{2}\left(n\theta\right)}{\sin\left(\theta\right)}.
}
$$
Maybe there was a missing negative in your attempt.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clarification!

Comment: No problem! @MusabUsman

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\frac{\cos(2n\theta)+i\sin(2n\theta)-1}{2i\sin\theta}
 = \frac{\sin(2n\theta)}{2\sin(\theta)} + \frac{1}{i}\frac{\cos(2n \theta) - 1}{2 \sin\theta}.$$
Since $\frac1i = -i$, the imaginary part of the above quantity will be $\frac{1 - \cos(2n \theta)}{2 \sin\theta}$. You have written the negative of that.